# Error in code, What's wrong?

Tags: c, macos, double, scanf

I've got an Problem. Whats the error in this code? It will give an Segmentation fault: 11

```
{
double os;
double windows = 2;

printf("Network info\n");

printf("Are you on Linux, OS X, or Windows? (1,2,3): ");
scanf("%s", os);
printf("checking..\n");
if (os == windows){
    printf("Getting informatin for windows..\n");
    system("ipconfig");
  }else{
    printf("Getting info for either osx or Linux..\n");
    system("ifconfig");
  }
}
```

Comment: Doubles are not null-terminated char arrays.

Comment: You take input in `double` using `%s` . Use `%lf`  for that .

Comment: you shouldn't use double for selections and should use %d for reading decimals

Comment: Why exactly do you need `double` here? Is there more code? You could just take in `int`. Or `char`.

Comment: have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to see how scanf works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you should change

```
scanf("%s", os);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &os);
```

as, `os` is of `double` type. Using wrong format specifier (or wrong argument type) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `scanf()` for further information.

FWIW, for an integer value, it's best to use `int` datatype.

Comment: Thanks, it works now!